# Quantstrat / Blotter dims error when running Trade Statistics

Tags: r, quantstrat, blotter

There is an **xts** object generated from a txt file.  It contains 5 rows: Open, High, Low, Close, S_Base. S_Base is a binary signal which is TRUE (equal to 1) when Low = Close. Thought to make a minimum reproducible example of 55 rows. It has 4 TRUE signals.

The quantstrat code below enters long when signal TRUE and goes flat when signal FALSE. This results in the system closing the position the period after opening.
The system generates 4 round trips. It works just fine. But the **blotter** package function `perTradeStats` gives the following error:

```
Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : 
dims [product 2] do not match the length of object [0]
```

If I apply the same code to an xts generated by downloading a ticker from Google (using some simple SMA crossover as signal), there is no error. I can't figure out why. Below is the code for the minimum reproducible example. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
# Install Packages
#install.packages("devtools")
#require(devtools)
#install_github("braverock/FinancialInstrument")
#install_github("joshuaulrich/xts") #needed as latest version on repository is older
#install_github("braverock/blotter")
#install.packages("quantstrat", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
#install_github("braverock/PerformanceAnalytics")

# Libraries
library(quantstrat)   
library(knitr)        

# Data
DTT3 <- structure(c(126.33, 126.37, 126.42, 126.3, 126.31, 126.31, 126.31,126.37, 126.41, 126.42, 126.38, 126.33, 126.38, 126.38, 126.36, 126.39, 126.42, 126.42, 126.43, 126.43, 126.42, 126.39, 126.47, 126.56, 126.53, 126.5, 126.43, 126.45, 126.5, 126.42, 126.39, 126.39, 126.37, 126.24, 126.21, 126.15, 126.21, 126.24, 126.24, 126.25, 126.25, 126.2, 126.18, 126.21, 126.15, 126.16, 126.03, 125.94, 125.97, 125.97, 125.7, 125.73, 125.73, 125.55, 126.38, 126.47, 126.43, 126.35, 126.32, 126.37, 126.37, 126.43, 126.44, 126.43, 126.39, 126.39, 126.42, 126.38, 126.38, 126.44, 126.44, 126.44, 126.44, 126.44, 126.42, 126.5, 126.56, 126.57, 126.55, 126.52, 126.56, 126.5, 126.52, 126.44, 126.43, 126.42, 126.41, 126.29, 126.22, 126.29, 126.24, 126.3, 126.25, 126.27, 126.3, 126.2, 126.25, 126.21, 126.2, 126.17, 126.03, 126.04, 126.02, 125.97, 126.04, 125.89, 125.81, 125.6, 126.32, 126.36, 126.3, 126.25, 126.26, 126.29, 126.29, 126.36, 126.4, 126.37, 126.32, 126.28, 126.36, 126.34, 126.36, 126.39, 126.36, 126.37, 126.41, 126.41, 126.35, 126.39, 126.43, 126.52, 126.48, 126.42, 126.4, 126.41, 126.36, 126.34, 126.35, 126.3, 126.22, 126.2, 126.14, 126.15, 126.15, 126.22, 126.18, 126.23, 126.15, 126.14, 126.15, 126.15, 126.09, 125.91, 125.87, 125.94, 125.9, 125.7, 125.67, 125.63, 125.54, 125.35, 126.37, 126.42, 126.3, 126.32, 126.3, 126.32, 126.36, 126.41, 126.42, 126.38, 126.33, 126.39, 126.38, 126.36, 126.38, 126.42, 126.44, 126.42, 126.44, 126.41, 126.4, 126.47, 126.55, 126.53, 126.5, 126.43, 126.45, 126.49, 126.42, 126.39, 126.38, 126.36, 126.25, 126.22, 126.16, 126.21, 126.23, 126.24, 126.25, 126.26, 126.21, 126.18, 126.2, 126.15, 126.16, 126.02, 125.95, 125.98, 125.97, 125.7, 125.73, 125.72, 125.55, 125.38, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1403483400, 1403484300, 1403485200, 1403486100, 1403487000, 1403487900, 1403488800, 1403489700, 1403490600, 1403491500, 1403492400, 1403493300, 1403494200, 1403495100, 1403496000, 1403496900, 1403497800, 1403498700, 1403499600, 1403500500, 1403501400, 1403502300, 1403503200, 1403504100, 1403505000, 1403505900, 1403506800, 1403507700, 1403508600, 1403509500, 1403510400, 1403511300, 1403512200, 1403513100, 1403514000, 1403514900, 1403515800, 1403516700, 1403517600, 1403518500, 1403519400, 1403520300, 1403521200, 1403522100, 1403523000, 1403523900, 1403524800, 1403525700, 1403526600, 1403527500, 1403528400, 1403529300, 1403530200, 1403531100), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(54L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "S_Base")))

# Basics
Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")      
currency("USD")               
initeq <- 30000

# Symbols
basic_symbols <- function() {symbols <- c("DTT3")}
symbols <- basic_symbols()
future(symbols, currency = "USD", multiplier = 1000)

# Strategy/Portfolio/Account
strategy.st <- "basicstrat"
portfolio.st <- "basicstrat"
account.st <- "basicstrat"
rm.strat(strategy.st)
rm.strat(portfolio.st)
initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols = symbols)
initAcct(account.st, portfolios = portfolio.st, initEq = initeq)
initOrders(portfolio.st, symbols = symbols)
strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE)

# Enter Long Signal
add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold",
           arguments = list(column = "S_Base",
                            threshold = 0,
                            relationship = "gt",     
                            cross = TRUE),           
           label = "longsig")

# Go Flat Signal
add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold",
           arguments = list(column = "S_Base",
                            threshold = 0,
                            relationship = "eq",
                            cross = TRUE),
           label = "flatsig")

# Enter Long Rule
add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "longsig",
                          sigval = TRUE,              
                          ordertype = "market",
                          prefer = "Open",            
                          orderside = "long",
                          orderqty = 1,
                          replace = FALSE),
         type = "enter")

# Go Flat Rule
add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "flatsig",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          ordertype = "market",
                          prefer = "Open",            
                          orderside = "long",
                          orderqty = "all",
                          replace = TRUE),        
         type = "exit")

# Apply Strategy
applyStrategy(strategy.st, portfolio.st)
updatePortf(portfolio.st)
updateAcct(account.st)
updateEndEq(account.st)

# Table: Summary Trade Stats
tstats <- tradeStats(portfolio.st)
kable(t(tstats))

### NO ERRORS ABOVE - FOLLOWING CODE PRODUCES THE ERROR/ERRORS ###

# Table: Per Trade Stats               
for(symbol in symbols) {
  pts <- perTradeStats(portfolio.st, Symbol = "DTT3")
  kable(pts, booktabs = TRUE, caption = symbol)}
kable(pts)

#Chart: Maximum Adverse Excursion 
for(symbol in symbols) {
  chart.ME(Portfolio = portfolio.st, Symbol = symbol, type = "MAE", 
           scale = "percent")}
```

Comment: I get no error when I run this code as is with this example.  I'm using the latest version of quantstrat `install_github("braverock/quantstrat")`

Comment: That could be the answer. I am using `quantstrat_0.9.1739`, your version is `0.10.2`. I won't know for now as after updating `quantstrat` with `install_github("braverock/quantstrat")` the package won't load anymore, getting error messages. Will tackle separately as different issues. Thank you.